# Mkdir and Insmod - File Exists error

Tags: linux, mkdir

Any ideas what im doing wrong?

```
mkdir /mnt/zmg
mount -t cifs -o username=Administrator,password=*****,domain=Provisorio,noserverino //10.20.30.1/zmg /mnt/zmg
insmod /mnt/zmg/tntfs.ko
```

Heres a print of the erros on bash:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/mnt/zmg' : File exists
mount error(16): Device or resource busy
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /mnt/zmg/tntfs.ko: File exists
/#
```

EDIT: About insmod error, i solve it with add "rmmod /mnt/zmg/tntfs.ko" before insmod call

Comment: Run `df` and `lsmod`.  Perhaps `/mnt/zmg` is already mounted and the kernel module is already loaded ?

Comment: can you show me changes that ive to do?

Comment: @roaima, text added

Answer (score 2):

You are not doing anything wrong.  All of those error messages are telling you that the operation has already been performed.  Run `lsmod | grep ntfs` (or maybe just `lsmod`) to confirm.

Perhaps those commands are in startup script, so get executed automatically on boot?  Or perhaps someone else ran them?  Or perhaps you ran them yourself, but since none of them have any output on success, they all worked and you didn't realise it?

Comment: In fact, the code are executed by server. As a client, im only have to type "img" on bash to select a proper (zenworks) image to restore. 
My main goal is clear or solve those errors. Next step, is automatize "img" command.